# how do you test if there is a next or prev post?

Tags: wordpress

i tried this :

```
<?php $prev=get_previous_posts_link();
if  (strlen($prev) == 0)
{
    echo "no posts";
}
else
{
    echo $prev;
}
?>
```

it always returns no posts!

Comment: And you're sure that there is more posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you use should be placed within the **loop**.
ie. inside,

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
.......
.......
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Your code might not be inside the **loop** and it could be the only reason why it always return no posts!